# Who directs the personas used by WWE wrestlers?

Tags: wwe

Who directs the personas used by WWE wrestlers?

Do they come up with the personas themselves, or are they determined for them by WWE executives?

For example, who would have told the WWE wrestler Undertaker to use the "[American Bad Ass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Undertaker#American_Bad_Ass_(2000%E2%80%932001))" persona?

Comment: @F1Krazy I think this question is on-topic, as it's about the story part of WWE. See [this Meta discussion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1449/63559)

Comment: I would recommend listening to Steve Austin podcast if you want to know more about the business side of this business.  He has talked to some of the big characters in the business and how they got there names and personas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do they come up with the personas themselves, or are they determined for them by WWE executives?

From watching behind the scenes media from the WWE (*Tough Enough* / *Breaking Ground* etc) and other available content.

Wrestlers are encouraged to come up with their "gimmick/persona" (subject to WWE approval) and see if it resonates with the trainers/executives and limited live audiences at their training facility (the WWE Perfomance center) (See *WWE NXT*).

However, the overall character arcs (and often live scripting) is, in general, under the "creative control" of the WWE Creative Team.

Few wrestlers are given a free hand over their promos and only the most trusted are allowed this privilege.

---

As for The Undertaker specifically...that was his (Mark Calaway) own idea.

> Undertaker made a radical switch to his character as he dumped his sinister and supernatural persona of The Deadman that saw him coming out in mortician-themed attires and putting together satanic groups for 10 years.
>
> He adopted the American Badass gimmick and came back as a biker who rode a motorcycle to the ring and wore bandanas, sunglasses and blue jeans.
>
> According to Sportskeeda, on an edition of Something Else to Wrestle with Bruce Prichard, the former manager claimed Undertaker wanted to adopt a new character that would make him look more like the guy he is in real life with the only difference being that he would carry out the new gimmick with more intensity.
>
> Prichard said: “He wanted to be the biker, he wanted to be the guy that he is in everyday life. Of course, with the volume turned up quite a bit.
>
> > “So there really wasn’t a whole lot of ‘what if we did this? What if we did that?’ It was, if we’re gonna change that was something he was immediately comfortable with.”
>
> The former manager also revealed that he and WWE Chairman Vince McMahon saw the new gimmick as a temporary change as the wrestling supremo wanted him to ultimately return to The Deadman persona.
>
> The seven-time world champion, however, disagreed with the idea and insisted that once his new image was presented there would be no turning back.
>
> Prichard and McMahon agreed to disagree with the ex-WWE Champion and just focused on making the new gimmick work for the time being.
>
> [Source](https://www.express.co.uk/sport/wwe/981261/WWE-news-Undertaker-Bruce-Prichard-Vince-McMahon-Roman-Reigns-Braun-Strowman-Elias)

Comment: An interesting fact is that WWE get a little bit of all of John Cena paychecks since they own that name.